# Define a syntax error in Lisp function

Tags: lisp

I am bad at Lisp. Help me please to find a syntax error. I need to write a function which swaps two elements in list. This function must consist loop-cycle. Here is what if have so far.

```
(defun swap-two-element(z x y)
  (let ((newlist nil) (newlist2 nil) (copyz z) (copyz2 z) (newx nil))
    (loop
      (when (= (- (length z) (length copyz2)) y)
        (return (set newx car z)))
      (setq newlist2 (append newlist2(car copyz2))
            copyz2 (cdr copyz2)))))
```

Call example: `(swap-two-element '(a b c d) 2 3)`

Comment: What does your error message say? Also, look at some lisp examples around and use some spaces. It will be a lot easier to read the code to understand it.

Comment: ;Compiler warnings :
;   In SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT: In the call to SET with arguments (NEWX CAR Z),
;     3 arguments were provided, but at most 2 are accepted
;     by the current global definition of SET
;   In SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT: Undeclared free variable CAR
;   In SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT: Unused lexical variable COPYZ
;   In SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT: Unused lexical variable NEWLIST
;   In SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT: Unused lexical variable X

Comment: Backtrace:
  0: (CCL::APPEND-2 A B)
  1: (SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT (A B C D) 2 3)
  2: (CCL::CALL-CHECK-REGS SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT (A B C D) 2 3)
  3: (CCL::CHEAP-EVAL (SWAP-TWO-ELEMENT '(A B C D) 2 3))

Comment: I took liberty to format the code and replace `cond` with `when` to comply with the CL coding standards and make it easier for other lispers to read it.

Comment: @sds You also took the liberty of replacing `set` with `values`, which makes the problem go away.  :(  The error message OP posted says "In the call to SET with arguments ...", but as you've left the code, it doesn't call `set` at all.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: sorry, I guess I got carried away :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the word [`set`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set.htm) with the word [`values`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_values.htm) and you are good to go.

PS. You need to address the warnings though, and explain what the function is supposed to do so that we could help you with the algorithm.

Comment: Actually, OP isn't 'good to go' after this.  There are other problems with this code (as indicated in the warnings in the comments (e.g., the variable `car` isn't bound, etc.)).

Answer (score 0):

You really need to tidy up your question. The title says nothing, the code is badly formatted and you really need to [play around with loop](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) to get started. I won't give you your solution since you need to learn this by trying. Here is an example you can make use of to do your assignment.

```lisp
;; this orders a list by their odd index
;; NB: index starts at zero so first element is even
(defun order-odd-index (list)
  (loop :for element :in list                ; iterates your list
        :for index :from 0                   ; starts from 0 and goes on
        :if (oddp index)                     ; if in a loop
           :collect element :into odd-list   ; variable is automatically created
        :else                                ; else in a loop
           :collect element :into even-list
        :finally (return (append odd-list even-list)))) ; what to do in the end

(order-odd-index '(4 67 3 2 7 9)) ; ==> (67 2 9 4 3 7)
```

I use keywords (like `:for` instead of `for`) to indicate what symbols are loop keywords and what are not. It's optional but I think it looks a lot cleaner.

Now your problem can be solved with collecting element into 5 variables. Two of them is when index is equal to one of the places (given as arguments) to be switched the other 3 are before, in between and greater. In the finally you can just `append` those variables in the correct order and you're done.